# How to update metadata of NuGet Package using command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am using NuGet.Exe version 2.8.2 to create nuget package. After Create Package, Open with NuGet Package Explorer and I saw there is some default code inside package like  in icon URL text box

> http:// icon_url_here_or_delete_this_line/

To see such data follow steps as foolows

1. Open command Line Box (cmc.exe).
2. Go to folder where NuGet.exe is present.
3. Run Command "nuget spec abc.dll" (abc.dll must present inside folder)
4. once abc.dll.spec file create the run " nuget pack abc.dll.spec "
5. done with creating package with some warnings about that default code in metadata.
6. Now open that package with Nuget Package explorer you can see that metadata with some default code like I mention above.

   I also refer document present in [this link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference) provided by nuget.Org.

So the question is that how to set my customize information to this metadata using command line?
**NOTE :-**
Please do not suggest to do it using Nuget Package Explorer because I know it I just want to use command line to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think NuGet.exe supports it. You can manually edit the .nuspec file in notepad, and replace the metadata like project URL; or do string replacement of the .nuspec file using powershell commands.

Comment: are you sure Dan Liu ? Is there document or any reference to your sentence please provide it.